# Removing Font outline when stroke is set to none

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, stroke

I'm having issues trying to remove the stroke from my text which has no stroke set. I've also tried different fonts however the stroke(or outline?) remains the same.

How can I go about removing this?

[image: Stroked Font]

Comment: I had the same issue sometimes with some fonts on Indesign, did you try restarting Illustrator? If nothing happen, restart the computer.

Comment: @Danielillo Unfortunately that did not fix the issue.

Comment: Are you using a special font manager?

Comment: Are you in the outline mode/view?

Comment: I've never seen this. Must be a setting somewhere you have or the font is bad.. or some third party voodoo. Can't be outline mode because live type is solid in outline mode.

Comment: Do you have a layer/group with effects applied? Showing your layer tree expanded would help here.

Answer (score 1):

In the menu at the top of your screen, go to "View." When in "View" ensure that you're in "GPU Preview." If you see "Outline", then you're in the wrong screen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the OP was in outline mode, the editable text would appear solid and the area outside the artboard would be white.

Comment: Hmmm. I see. If the text has been outlined my pix are correct. However if the text has not been outlined then you're correct, @zeethreepio

Comment: Based on the OP's image, it appears that the text is still editable and "create outlines" is still an option.

Comment: @zeethreepio My impression is that the text is highlighted for an adjustment. Which is why it shows up as outlined. But, if it were not selected, it would be all white. If that were the case, placing it on a color, and deselecting it, the 'outline' would disappear.